# Tap Push Notification When application is not active force close in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with push notification. When my application in background, and I got the notification and I tap the notification it work and go to the view controller I want. But when the application is closed and I tap the notification, the application will be force closed. This is my method to parse push notification in FinishedLaunching

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary options)
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                var pushSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                        new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            else
            {
                var notificationType = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge
                                       | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationType);
            }
            if (options != null && options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
            {
                var userInfo = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary;
                if (userInfo != null)
                {
                    var response = this.ParseResponse(userInfo);
                    this.ShowNotifications(response, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Refresh();
            }

            return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching(application, options);
        }
```

and this is how I parse response from userInfo

```
private GCMResponse ParseResponse(NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            NSObject title,
                     message,
                     page;
            userInfo.TryGetValue(new NSString("Title"), out title);
            userInfo.TryGetValue(new NSString("Message"), out message);
            userInfo.TryGetValue(new NSString("Page"), out page);

            return new GCMResponse
            {
                Message = message?.ToString() ?? string.Empty,
                Page = page?.ToString() ?? string.Empty,
                Title = title?.ToString() ?? string.Empty
            };
        }
```

And this is how I will show and process which page should I show when user tap push notification

```
private void ShowNotifications(GCMResponse response, bool isFromFinishLaunch = false)
        {
                this.Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                var activitiesViewController =
                        (ActivitiesViewController)storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ActivitiesViewController");
                    navController.PushViewController(activitiesViewController, false);
                    if (!isFromFinishLaunch)
                    {
                        if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Window.RootViewController = rootController;
                            Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Window.RootViewController = rootController;
                        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
                    }
                    this.RootViewController = rootController;
                }
            }
        }
```

For note, I am also doing like this in ReceivedRemoteNotification and it work fine

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            var response = this.ParseResponse(userInfo);
            this.ShowNotifications(response);
        }
```

And also, how I can debug my app from Xamarin Studio when app is closed and I get push notifications? Because whenever the app closes, the debugger also lost.

Comment: "application is closed and I tap the notification, the application will be force closed." If the application is already closed then how can it be forced closed? But what does forced closed even mean??

Comment: What I mean in here is app opened for a while then it force closed again and go back to my homescreen

Comment: yes... a crash that I mean

Comment: Then you need to find out which line is causing the crash, use Xcode, or even logging if you have to.

Comment: And I get trouble how to debug it. Because when app is closed the debugger also lost so I can't use debugger to debug it. And I don't know how to check console if debugger is already lost

Comment: Add NSLog statements, then use Xcode's Window|Devices|to view the log output, use that to find out where the problem is occurring.